# Design time errors when working in .NET 3.5 and adding charts after reopening the designer

Tags: winforms, charts, .net-3.5

Unfortunalty I need to use .NET 3.5 and use charts in the designer. Everything works quite well. I have added a package Microsoft Chart Controls that are not there by default with .NET 3.5 and added the dlls to the tools bar and to the reference.

I able to have the chart displayed in the designer and work with its data in the class. Problems start if I close the designer window and then open it again - I get a bunch of design time errors!

The strangest thing is that the code compiles and the chart works well in the application. Also the code behind in the auto generated design.cs stays untouched but i get millions of errors such as:

[image]

Has anyone come across a similar situation? Don't know how to go around it. I am using Visual Studio 2017. Thanks!

Comment: If I click ignore and continue and form works but chart controls don't display. However I am able to add another chart and the same story repeats itslef.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add reference of this dll

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
```

If this error will showing continuously then

Please add a new Winform and add a chart control.

then write your code in new created form . it will work.